# formatting URL to single type

Tags: php, url

I have a text-box, where I will be getting URL

URLs can be entered in any of the following format:

```
 example.com
 www.example.com

 http://example.com
 http://www.example.com

 example.com/
 www.example.com/

 http://example.com/
 http://www.example.com/
```

I need to convert them to single

```
http://example.com/
```

How can I do it, there must be simple way round to do it, right?

Comment: www.example.com and example.com are two different hostnames and may host two completely different websites (or no websites, or only one of them might host a website). Assuming they are the same in the general case is a big mistake.

Comment: @David Dorward: Good point. It's not a good idea, but if it is that, what he wants...

Comment: @David Dorward: My requirements are clearly mentioned in my question, I know that with and without 'www' are 2 different scenarios, but I don't mind it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only expect this few variations you could solve this, with a regex. For example

```
<?php
// $input = The data you retrieved

$output = preg_replace('#^(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)/?$#', 'http://$1/', $input);
echo $output;
```

I didn't test it, but should work.. If not, let me know :)

** Edit **
Just tested it. Works fine. At least for the formats you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a regular expression with some optional parts. It seems the optional parts of your string are...

- http://
- www.
- trailing /

Here is some code...

```
$text = "http://example.com";
if (preg_match('%^(http://)?(www\.)?(.*?)(/)?$%i', $text, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[3];
    // $result now contains example.com - add whatever wrapper you need to it
}
```

Comment: You forget to escape the `.` after the `www`. Also using preg_replace instead of preg_match would give you the final result right away :)